# Weird issue with NewRelic MySQL metrics

Tags: mysql, newrelic-platform

I'm using NewRelic MySQL plugin (1.0.7 for now) for 2+ months; there are 4 MySQL servers (MySQL 5.5).
The problem that recently (last 10 days) I see wrong metrics for one of my DB server, for example newrelic shows 0 writes/sec. 
Any ideas how to debug/fix this?

Comment: I'd suggest starting by looking at the logs for any obvious errors. If it looks like data is being collected (no permissions issues) you should perhaps confirm with New Relic that the data is making it to their servers.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug with read/writes in version 1.1.0 - if you upgrade to the latest version (1.2.0) from https://rpm.newrelic.com/extensions/com.newrelic.plugins.mysql.instance you shouldn't see the problem any longer.

Comment: thank you.already reverted to 1.0.8; will wait with upgrade - 1.2.0 is too young :-)